# Accessing an item beyond start_index=1000 in a YouTube user upload feed

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, gdata

I am currently trying to pull data about videos from a YouTube user upload feed. This feed contains all of the videos uploaded by a certain user, and is accessed from the API by a request to:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/USERNAME/uploads
```

Where USERNAME is the name of the YouTube user who owns the feed.

However, I have encountered problems when trying to access feeds which are longer than 1000 videos. Since each request to the API can return 50 items, I am iterating through the feed using max_length and start_index as follows:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/USERNAME/uploads?start-index=1&max-results=50&orderby=published
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/USERNAME/uploads?start-index=51&max-results=50&orderby=published
```

And so on, incrementing start_index by 50 on each call. This works perfectly up until:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/USERNAME/uploads?start-index=1001&max-results=50&orderby=published
```

At which point I receive a 400 error informing me that 'You cannot request beyond item 1000.' This confused me as I assumed that the query would have only returned 50 videos: 1001-1051 in the order of most recently published.  Having looked through the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference), I discovered this:

> **Limits on result counts and accessible results**
>
> ...
>
> For any given query, you will not be able to retrieve more than 1,000
>   results even if there are more than that. The API will return an error
>   if you try to retrieve greater than 1,000 results. Thus, the API will
>   return an error if you set the start-index query parameter to a value
>   of 1001 or greater. It will also return an error if the sum of the
>   start-index and max-results parameters is greater than 1,001.
>
> For example, if you set the start-index parameter value to 1000, then
>   you must set the max-results parameter value to 1, and if you set the
>   start-index parameter value to 980, then you must set the max-results
>   parameter value to 21 or less.

I am at a loss about how to access a generic user's 1001st last uploaded video and beyond in a consistent fashion, since they cannot be indexed using only max-results and start-index. Does anyone have any useful suggestions for how to avoid this problem? I hope that I've outlined the difficulty clearly!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Getting all the videos for a given account **is** supported, but you need to make sure that your request for the uploads feed is going against the backend database and not the search index. Because you're including `orderby=published` in your request URL, you're going against the search index. Search index feeds are limited to 1000 entries.

Get rid of the `orderby=published` and you'll get the data you're looking for. The default ordering of the uploads feed is reverse-chronological anyway.

This is a particularly easy mistake to make, and we have a blog post up explaining it in more detail:

http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/03/keeping-things-fresh.html

The nice thing is that this is something that will no longer be a problem in version 3 of the API.

Comment: +1. Thanks for clearing this up. I deleted my answer, since it was completely incorrect and only likely to confuse people

Comment: Fantastic, thanks Jeff. I will change my query correspondingly!