# Pulling exhaustive watched video list from Youtube API (>1000 items)

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I recently started exploring the Youtube API in order to pull some long-term data about what videos I've watched over the past year and when. I'm currently able to pull in my watched video list, but unfortunately I'm hitting the 1000 item cap. I think the issue is related to the ones found in [Accessing an item beyond start_index=1000 in a YouTube user upload feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708333/accessing-an-item-beyond-start-index-1000-in-a-youtube-user-upload-feed), where tweaking the request URL can change whether results are coming from the search cache or not.

Most of the similar questions on here deal with requesting urls that include some sort of sorting that would trigger the 1000 item cap, but I'm just running with basic URls such as https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/watch_history?v=2&start-index=1000&max-results=49 . Why would I be encountering the caps?

Answer (score 0):

For v3 the query quota adds up depending on how many returned items you have request or not being restrictive enough. Various query entries cost more and can multiple.

This might not apply for the OP but for the v3 API it is all layout in the reference. Maybe code in some quota keeping logic so you can get a better understanding.